# Moderation attention flags don't add up

Tags: support, flag-history

My current flag counters look as below:

```
35  moderator attention flags
3   waiting for review
20  deemed helpful
1   declined
3   disputed
```

`3 + 20 + 1 + 3 = 27`

Where did my 8 remaining flags gone? It is any additional, hidden status of a flag?

Comment: "**older flags were not recorded helpful/declined*"

Comment: @TinyGiant What does "older" means exactly? I flagged something in February 2015 first. Of what I remember, this information was there in that time.

Comment: @TinyGiant That almost never explains anything nowadays. Unless your account is at least ~4 years old, that line will not be relevant to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eight of your flags have aged away because they sat around for too long. This mostly happens with recommend closure flags. This outcome is not currently listed in the sidebar.

Comment: I thought that "disputed" means elapsed timeout.

Comment: Disputed means that the community reviewed it and disagreed. That doesn't fit well with flags that age away, because aged away inherently means no one ever looked at it.

Comment: Aged away now appears in the sidebar stats so the totals should now match.